# How to convert system() in python to subprocess call to execute a ssh command?

Tags: python, subprocess

I know it's a very stupid question, but I am having some difficulty in wrapping around my head to convert this `system()` command into an equivalent subprocess call to execute the ssh command. My current `system()` call is:

```
cmd_txt = "ssh -i pem_file.pem user1@" + host_ip + " ' cd /folder1/folder2 && java -cp jar_filw.jar -a arg1 -t arg2 -e arg3 -f /folder1/folder2/folder3/file1_" + suffix + ".txt'"
```

I am having difficulty especially around the `cd` and `java -cp` part. Can anyone show what would be the equivalent subprocess call to execute this command?

**NOTE**: `host_ip` and `suffix` are variables.

Comment: there is a library named paramiko, which might handle the ssh, but for subprocess, just refer pyprogrammer's answer

Answer (score 0):

Use "subprocess.Popen"

```
cmd_txt = "ssh -i pem_file.pem user1@" + host_ip + " ' cd /folder1/folder2 && java -cp jar_filw.jar -a arg1 -t arg2 -e arg3 -f /folder1/folder2/folder3/file1_" + suffix + ".txt'"

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_txt, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

**shell=True**
means that the text is like it would be written to command prompt

then u can communicate with subprocess with PIPEs

```
output = p.communicate()[0]
```

Or commands can be supplied as a list of strings

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "arg1", "arg2"])
```

for more info see the docs
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar to subprocess.Popen:

```
subprocess.call(cmd_txt, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

would also work